# extraneous key [HealthCheck] is not permitted

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm kinda stuck with this weird error.
I'm deploying an ECS Task (Fargate) using a CloudFormation script, it works and successfully deploy the Task. But when the HealthCheck property is set Cloudformation replies

`Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#: extraneous key [HealthCheck] is not permitted)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)`

and my task definition is :

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Sub ${ServiceName}-${EnvironmentName}
      Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'
      Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/some-iam-role
      HealthCheck:
        Command:
          - [ CMD-SHELL,./compose/healthcheck.sh || exit 1 ]
        Interval: 10
        Retries: 5
        StartPeriod: 30
        Timeout: 5
      TaskRoleArn:
        Fn::If:
          - 'HasCustomRole'
          - !Ref 'Role'
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'
          Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'
          Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: 'awslogs'
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Sub ${ServiceName}-service-${EnvironmentName}
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          Environment:
            - <some other environment that work ok>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HealthCheck`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-healthcheck) is a sub-property of [`AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition.ContainerDefinition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html), not a top-level property of [`AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html)

Comment: thank you! 

aws documentation wasn't that clear on that 

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-healthcheck.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-healthcheck-command

Comment: That was the case for me too, the title of the documentation page is `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition HealthCheck`, which caused the confusion.

I'd expect the title to be `HealthCheck (AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition)`